# How can I redirect to the same window after email confirmation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to implement two factor authentication by sending a confirmation email with a link

```
<a class="confirm-button" href="@url">Confirm</a>
...
string body = GetConfirmationMailBody();
body = body.replace("@url", $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}/UserAccount/CompleteConfirmEmail/?{ModelToQueryString(model)}");
```

to a controller action that validates a code for the user with a custom token provider and should redirect to the "Login" action if the code is correct. And I need to open the corresponding "Login" view in the same window as the current "Register" view. But confirmation mail link always open new browser window.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CompleteConfirmEmail(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    string action = "Register";
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model?.EmailVerificationCode))
    {
        BankApiUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model?.Email);
        if(user != null && await UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, Startup.Startup.TwoFactorTokenProviderName, model.EmailVerificationCode))
        {
            model.EmailConfirmationState = ConfirmationState.Complete;
            model.Submitted = false;
            action = "Login";
        }
    }
    if(model == null)
    {
        model = new RegisterViewModel();
    }
    string url = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}/UserAccount/{action}/?{model.ToQueryString()}";
    string target = "BankApi.Register";
    return RedirectToAction(action, model);
}
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(RegisterViewModel? regModel = null)
{
    LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel(regModel);
    return View(model);
}
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

I tried to set name to my current window in javascript.

```
window.name = "BankApi.Register";
```

And then open it by name.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CompleteConfirmEmail(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    string action = "Register";
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model?.EmailVerificationCode))
    {
        BankApiUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model?.Email);
        if(user != null && await UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, Startup.Startup.TwoFactorTokenProviderName, model.EmailVerificationCode))
        {
            model.EmailConfirmationState = ConfirmationState.Complete;
            model.Submitted = false;
            action = "Login";
        }
    }
    if(model == null)
    {
        model = new RegisterViewModel();
    }
    string url = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}/UserAccount/{action}/?{model.ToQueryString()}";
    string target = "BankApi.Register";
    return Content(@$"
        <script>
            try
            {{
                window.close();
                window.open({url}, {target});
            }}
            catch(e)
            {{
                console.error(e);
                throw e;
            }}
        </script>", 
        "text/html");
}
```

But it is not working. How can I open redirect link in the current window?

---

You can find more details in my solution repo: [BankAccountingPublic](https://github.com/pnfstas/BankAccountingPublic)

Comment: According to your code, you redirect to the `Register` method after confirming the email. Did you open a new browser window when you were redirected to `Register`? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Chen During the email confirmation, I redirect to either the "Login" action if the email is validated successfully, or to the "Login" action if the validation fails. Current view "Register" stays open. And additionally new window is opened for "Login" or "Register" view, created by redirect. I added a link to my solution repository.

Comment: What about to use SignalR to push content to the login page. In your CompleteConfirmEmail action you could push to the client the confirmation. In this way you could manage a context in wich the email is opened in a mobile phone and the user is logging in in a desktop browser.